# Recyclerview Binding in Another Fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, data-binding

With the help of room, i am testing a simple app to save words. I have 2 layout fragment- home(main) and myword(second). I am trying to put the following code in myword fragment to initialize recyclerview, i am getting unresolve error. What am i putting wrong?

***frag_mywords.xml***

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/words_dail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recykel_list"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

***TakerFragment.kt***

```
class TakerFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var takerViewModel: TakerViewModel
private var _binding: FragMywordsBinding? = null

private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    takerViewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(TakerViewModel::class.java)

    _binding = FragMywordsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.words_dail)
    val adapter = WordListAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    return root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
   }
}
```

**How do i correctly solved this line?**

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.words_dail)
    val adapter = WordListAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Comment: Could you post the exact stacktrace? And `findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)` might not be right, because your RecyclerView ID is `words_dail`. So it should be `findViewById<RecyclerView> (R.id.words_dail)`. But you don't need to use `findViewById` anymore, use kotlin syntethics. So just write `val recyclerview = words_dail` and then import the syntethics

Comment: yes i corrected words_dail. here is stacktrace https://pastebin.com/hL0nHpUJ

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here:

First change `val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.words_dail)` with `val recyclerView = words_dail`.

Then, the context of your WorldListAdapter is wrong, it should be `val adapter = WordListAdapter(requireContext())` and not `this`.

Third, you can set the layoutManager in the `xml` with this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/words_dail"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
tools:listitem="@layout/recykel_list"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" <--
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

With Databinding you could also set the adapter in the xml but I don't know if you use databinding in your adapter.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The val recyclerView = wordds_dail still gives unreference error. And no i didnt use data binding in adapter. https://pastebin.com/JkFaDK2U

Comment: Well did you import the syntethics?

Comment: Seems i fixed it temporarily by mapping it to new activity instead of fragment. I still can't get fragment to work.